# symfony2 native query is null but the sql query has one

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

has anybody an idea why the nativequery result is null?

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('AcmeTestBundle:event', 'e');
$rsm->addFieldResult('e', 'id', 'id');

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery('SELECT id FROM event WHERE publickey COLLATE latin1_general_cs = ?', $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $eventkey);

return $query->getSingleResult();
```

When i run the query directly in mysql, i get the correct result.
This is the created query from the console:

```
[2012-06-24 18:08:08] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT id FROM event WHERE publickey COLLATE latin1_general_cs = ? (["key"]) [] []
```

I'm using the same function on another entity and i get the correct result.
Has anybody an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to add all entity fields in your ResultSetMapping.

Actually, with only the id, doctrine can't hydrate your object.

Comment: i will just check if a row exists, i don't need the whole object. The same usage works on an other entity. :-/

Comment: If you don't need hydratation, why don't you directly use DBAL?

Comment: I think this is the only way to2 check a select statement case sensitive. For anything else i need the DBAL. Do you know an other case to check case senstivie with doctrine2?

Comment: Maybe something like this is enough:
`$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->query('your query here')-> fetch()`